# HttpClient parallel calls - how to distribute workload across servers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, load-balancing, dotnet-httpclient

I am building a .Net 6.0 console app, where I have a need to make parallel httpClient calls in bulk. One the API hosting side, its hosted internally. We have a URL CName pointing to Global Load balancer URL which is load balancing between 2 LTM VIP URLs (each VIP load balancing with 3 server members). So total 6 servers hosting the API. The console app is running on a different server. Same team owns both the console app as well as the APIs.

Assuming that I either use a Singleton or static httpClient, when I place multiple Get or Post requests in parallel, does the request eventually resolve and arrive at a single server to which the connection was first established? The API calls will be POST calls performing some bulk operations including database inserts. So it will be resource heavy both in terms of memory and CPU.

So essentially, what I am trying to find is how do I avoid bombarding a single API server with all requests from my batch app, but instead be able to distribute the workload across all the available servers? If its not possible to distribute the workload using httpclient , what other alternative options that I can look at?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you conducted any experiments, yet?

Comment: I mean: do you have numbers that support your hypothesis that you _will_ be running into _that_ problem?